# How to repeat an image without using JavaScript?

Tags: html, css

I am working on an assignment and I can’t quite figure out what to do. The assignment is that I need to use the image created and make it a tile. We have not learned how to use JavaScript so my search comes up empty. Here is the HTML + CSS code I have to work with:

```css
body {
  width: 800px;
  background-color: black
}
.outer1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  background-color: lightgreen
}
.outer2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  background-color: lightgreen
}
.inner1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  border-radius: 50px 10px;
  background-color: green
}
.inner2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  border-radius: 10px 50px;
  background-color: green
}
div {
  float: left
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="outer1">
    <div class="inner1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="outer2">
    <div class="inner2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

If anyone can help me figure this out, with hopefully an explanation, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you search stack Overflow for CSS image repeat you should be able to find an answer. :-) FYI questions like these will probably get down voted and put on hold.

Comment: [Hint](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp)

Comment: There is no image in your html or css.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat

Answer (score 0):

Am I hallucinating but I don't see an image in your markup or css?

But, if you want to use an image and have it tile, use css background property and set it to repeat. You can also tell the image to repeat only on the x or y axis, which would give you a horizontal repeat only, or a vertical repeat only. You can see a lot of examples on W3schools.

For example, if you have a div that you want to give a background image to and have it repeat, typically this will be an image of something like a brick wall that has been designed and cropped to repeat without showing a seam where one tiled image starts and one ends.

Using your html above, I would assign the body element css of background-image and background-repeat to tile it across your site.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are looking for background image

```css
div {
    background-image: url("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a");
    background-repeat: repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="canvas">
        <script>
            for(x=0; x<=48;x++) {
                function create(htmlStr) {
                    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
                    temp = document.createElement('div');
                    temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;
                    while (temp.firstChild) {
                        frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
                    }
                    return frag;
                }
                var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
                var div_create = ""
                if (x % 2 === 0) {
                    div_create = "<div class='outer1', id="+x+"><div class='inner1'></div></div>"
                 }
                else {
                    div_create = "<div class='outer1', id="+x+"><div class='inner2'></div></div>"
                }
                divider = create(div_create)
                canvas.appendChild(divider)
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

<style>
    body{
    background-color:black;
    width: 800px;
    }

    .outer1{
        height: 100px; 
        width: 100px;border: 2px solid yellow;
        background-color: lightgreen 
    }

    .inner1{
        height: 100px; 
        width: 100px; 
        border: 2px solid yellow; 
        border-radius : 50px 10px; 
        background-color:green
    }

    .inner2{
        height: 100px; 
        width: 100px; 
        border: 2px solid yellow; 
    border-radius : 10px 50px;
    background-color:green
    }
</style>
</html>
```

Here this works all you have to do is change x in the for loop for the desired amount of squares. The ways this works is by looping the creation of divs via JavaScript to create that tiled mosaic effect - copy and paste the full code above for it to work

Comment: Really? You more focused on grammar that a viable solution

Comment: Thanks for doing that rather than expecting someone else to clean it up!